# GC overhead limit exceeded in code

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have written a code. The problem that I am facing is that when the "j" of for loop exceeds 1000 I start to get an error of "GC overhead limit exceeded". If I increase the allocated memory to 4GB I can iterate upto 2000 after which the same problem occurs. I want to keep this option of increasing the memory as the last resort and want to try to scale my code. The compiler highlights a problem with the statements where I have placed an arrow. 
Can someone please guide me that what could be the possible error here. 
I have already visited this question  [Error java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393486/error-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-gc-overhead-limit-exceeded)

```
     for (int j=1; j<=num_doc; j++) { 
        List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(Collections.nCopies(129039, 0));
        BufferedReader fl = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dataFolder+"file"+ " ("+j+")"+".int"));
        String line1;

        while((line1=fl.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] arr=line1.split(" ");//<---------------------
            line1="";
            int k = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
            Arrays.fill(arr, "");
            numb=numb+1;
            int temp=(list1.get(k))+1;
            list1.set(k, temp);
        }
        F_d.add(numb);
        numb=0;
        fl.close();
        ls2d.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(list1));//<---------------------
        list1.clear();
    }
```

Comment: Do you clear `ls2d` somewhere in your code?

Comment: Yes ls2d is used. I have pasted only that portion of the code that the compiler is highlighting.

Comment: `list1` is already quite big, so if you spend your time to add it to `ls2d` without clearing it, it will quickly take a lot of memory which leads to OOME

Comment: Its hard to understand what you really want to achieve here, but I'm almost 100% certain that there are easier ways to achieve your goal, with a fraction of the memory.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto list1.clear is already there

Comment: I'm talking about clearing `ls2d`not `list1`

Comment: `String[] arr=line1.split(" ");` and all the code after that seems to indicate the you only need the first element, which should be interpreted as an `int`. Confirm, deny, comment?

Comment: to save some memory you could use an array of the primitive type int instead of `List<Integer>`  for `list1`

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi True

Comment: Seems like you want to count occurrences of the integer in column 1 of each line into some memory structure, and that the maximum integer you expect is 129039. Especially because the number is fixed, a standard array would be much easier to work with, and much less memory intensive.

Comment: I am working on encryption, so due to the hashes, inverses and AES I had to implement it this way. But you have interpret this code snippet correctly.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto J represents number of documents. Each list1 corresponds to a document and I want to maintain it in a tabular form in ls2d. So I won't be able to clear it.

Answer (score 0):

Two things can be immediately optimized for less memory requirements:

```
        // we don't need all the fragments, taking only the first is fine
        String firstElem=line1.substring(0, line1.indexOf(" "));
        line1=null;// let GC collect this at its convenience
        int k = Integer.parseInt(firstElem);
```

then

```
    // Don't add the copy, add list1 itself
    // You are initing list1 in the beginning of the for cycle anyway
    // and until then nothing happens.
    ls2d.add(list1);//<---------------------
    // list1.clear(); -- since we added list1, we don't clear it anymore
```

Comment: I have made these changes and the error remains there

Comment: @Shahzaib - did the lines where OOM happened changed?

Comment: Yes, now it is a Java heap space error appearing at the ls2d.add(list1) of the code I had pasted

Comment: @Shahzaib - then at least what I suggested worked. Didn't solve the problems elsewhere. To solve the others, I'll need to know the how "dense" list1 is in non-zero components? (if it's mostly zero, then it's sparse and we can get rid of another big memory devourer).

Comment: @Shahzaib look, each iteration of the `for` cycle eats away at least `129039 x 4 = 500 kB` of memory. Can we do it with less without loosing information?

Comment: Thanks. It is not sparse. If we try to reduce to the size of the array then the decryption results will vary and I will loose my primary goal of decryption.

Comment: @Shahzaib And you really need an Int? Won't a short be enough? After all, the short can represent numbers as high as 32767, do you have values higher than that?

Comment: My numbers will range between 0-228199

Comment: Then go with the solution proposed by @fvu.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of ideas to reduce memory consumption - and runtime probably.

- use an array instead of an ArrayList - you don't seem to use ArrayList specific functionality so an array will be more compact and easier to work with
- tell split to just read the first field of a line

Note that I removed all code that was intended to coerce the garbage collector into cleaning up, I don't think it helps in this case.

---

```
 for (int j=1; j<=num_doc; j++) { 
    int[] list1 = new int[129039];

    BufferedReader fl = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dataFolder+"file"+ " ("+j+")"+".int"));
    String line1;

    while((line1=fl.readLine()) != null) {
        String[] arr=line1.split(" ",2); // Just read first field - see String Javadoc
        int k = Integer.parseInt(arr[0]);
        list[k]=list[k]+1;
        numb=numb+1;
    }
    F_d.add(numb);
    numb=0;
    fl.close();
    ls2d.add(list1);// you'll obviously need to change ls2d's type, or reconvert using Arrays.asList
}
```